# How to resize/transform touchscreen area with Wayland

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, wayland, touch-screen

I have an external monitor connected to a machine with a built-in touchscreen display. When setting a 16:10 external display to mirror the 16:9 touchscreen display, we get black bars on the touchscreen, the input range for the touchscreen does not resize to match the output. I need to find a scriptable way to make this change for any (single) external display with any aspect ratio and without user input. I already have a udev rule that runs a python script to automatically set a monitor to mirror.

I need to configure this on Debian 11 and GNOME Shell 3.38.6 without disabling Wayland, though the issue is also on Debian 12 with GNOME Shell 43.6.

My digging so far has come to several solutions that seem to be specific to X11 and multiple places indicating that Wayland does not currently have the capability I need. I’ve tried using the archived `python-libinput` and other recommendations to set a calibration matrix for `libinput`, but have yet to get something to work. Any help, guidance, or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: We discovered the mis-match with mirrored monitors, but it is reproduce-able by setting a touchscreen display to a non-default aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution? I encountered the same problem. When I mirror an external monitor of a different aspect ratio, my stylus position on the laptop scrren is always off because the top of the physical laptop screen is taken to be the top of the display (which is smaller than the physical screen due a mismatch in the aspect ratio).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/462840)

Comment: Our solution ended up being a shift in our requirements. I have also not gotten traction in a post to the GNOME forums nor in an issue opened with the mutter project.